# Matrix Multiplication with Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(128,128))
B = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(128,128))
```

I have those arrays. I would like to do matrix multiplication in several ways.

1. Row by Column
2. Row by Row
3. Column by Column
4. Block by Block.

I know 1 & 2.

For number 1, I use np.matmul(A,B)
number 2, I use np.multiply(A,B)

I'm not sure how to execute number 3 and 4. How we do matrix multiplication Column by Column and Block by Block.

Thank you

Comment: `np.multiply` is element-wise multiplication. What do you mean `Row by Row`?

Comment: You can do most of those with `matmul` if you transpose one the arrays.  `matmul` docs should be clear about how dimensions are paired.   `np.einsum` is another way of specifying combinations, with a lot of expressive power.  For `blocks` you might need to reshape (and transpose) the arrays first.

Comment: Although i like the umbrella topic, this is a list of poorly specified questions that's not conducive to someone writing up a good answer. My suggestion would be to ask clearly about a single type of multiplication (and you can include the others if you want, but not at the expense of clarifying the main one).